# Method "watch" has type "object" in the component definition. Did you reference the function correctly?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm building a Dropdown Component, and Vue is throwing me the following error:

```
Method "watch" has type "object" in the component definition. Did you reference the function correctly?

watch: {
    selected: function (val) {
      console.log("value changed", val);
    },
   }
```

I've done some research but I can't figure out how to correctly resolve this error, as it appears correct to me, let me know if I should attach some more relevant code. I'll attach my full methods below:

```
methods: {
updateSelectedValue: function (newValue) {
  this.selected = newValue;
},

addParam() {
  this.addFormFields(['params'], {
    slug: '',
    name: '',
    isRequired: true,
    description: '',
    typeSlug: '',
  });
},

deleteParam(idx){
  this.removeFormFields(['params', idx]);
},

restoreParam(idx){
  this.restoreFormFields(['params', idx])
},

$newObject() {
  return  {
    slug: '',
    name: '',
    isAbstract: false,
    requester: '',
    description: '',
    status: 'inactive',
    params: [],
    selected: '',
  };
},

$extraPrams() {
  return {
    parentId: this.parentId,
  };
},

   watch: {
    selected: function (val) {
      console.log("value changed", val);
    },
   }
  },
};
```

Answer (score 1):

it seems that you put `watch` in `methods`. it should be out of `methods`